# Cache tiles doesn't work in GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache

I've grouped some vector layers (from SHP files) in GeoServer (they are EPSG:2039) and created cache for them (GeoWebCache lets you choose EPSG:4326 OR EPSG:900913)
Once I've fired my App it didn't seem to read the cached tiles from the WMS (although they were created in the hard drive folder)

Could it be that because of the map projection the tiles are not being read ? (In the hard drive they are stored under EPSG_4326 folder)

This is how I init my map :

```
function init() {
        // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
        // and default to jpeg format
        format = 'image/png';

        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            155000, 600000,
            246000, 745000
        );
        var options = {                
            maxExtent: bounds,
            maxResolution: 566.40625,
            projection: "EPSG:2039",
            units: 'm'
        };
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

        // setup tiled layer
        tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "background", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/MyWorkspace/wms",
            {
                LAYERS: 'background',                    
                format: format,
                tiled: true,
                tilesOrigin: map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                isBaseLayer: true,
                yx: { 'EPSG:2039': false }
            }
        );

        map.addLayer(tiled);

        // build up all controls
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(200300,745000),7);            
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to cache tiles in projections other than the two defaults (4326, 900913) then you need to define a custom gridset with the new projection so that tiles in that projection are created.

The process is a little bit involved but is explained at http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/projections.html

Comment: Another point is that you can ensure that you're using GeoWebCache by using the GWC endpoint, located at /geoserver/gwc/service/wms?